# Why is Cypress not using this stubbed route?

Tags: cypress

I'm stubbing the following:

```
  cy.route("GET", "**/api/v2/equipment/brand/?website=*", {
    count: 0,
    next: null,
    previous: null,
    results: []
  }).as("findBrandsByWebsite");
```

But then I see that the stub is not been used.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: `cy.route()` is deprecated in newer versions of Cypress. I'd recommend trying it out with `cy.intercept()` and seeing if you still have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still not sure why that route wouldn't catch, but using it as a regular expression instead fixed the problem:

```js
  cy.route("GET", /\/api\/v2\/equipment\/brand\/\?website=.*/, {
    count: 0,
    next: null,
    previous: null,
    results: []
  }).as("findBrandsByWebsite");
```

Answer (score 2):

With `cy.intercept` there's a pattern that allows the query part to be defined separately [With RouteMatcher](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-RouteMatcher)

```js
cy.intercept({
  url: "**/api/v2/equipment/brand",
  query: { website: '*' },
})
```